# Java String spilter

Tags: java, string

I have a string of annotation of country abbreviation , I want to split them out so I can identify the country of each abbreviation. Such that I will have String c = USA; I will output the country name...

currently it doesnt have c = USA but only A

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "USAIND";

        String c = "";
        System.out.print("Country: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            c = Character.toString(x.charAt(i));
            System.out.print(c);
            if (c.equals("USA")) {
                System.out.println("United State of America");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Country: ");
        for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++) {

            c = Character.toString(x.charAt(i));

            System.out.print(c);
            if (c.equals("IND")) {
                System.out.println("India");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");

    }
}
```

Comment: How come a single character be equals to "USA" or "IND" , use substring method instead. `"USAIND".substring(3).equals("IND")` or `"USAIND".substring(0,3).equals("USA")`

Comment: One big thing I see here is that `c` should be a `StringBuilder`, not a `String`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to append each character to your String and then compare it, otherwise, it'll just keep replacing your String with the last character always.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    c += Character.toString(x.charAt(i)); // Appending all the characters one by one
}

System.out.print(c); // Printing the String c after all the characters are appending

if (c.equals("USA")) { // checking if its equal to USA
    System.out.println("United State of America");
}
```

And the same goes with the other half of the process.

```
c = ""; // re-initialize it to blank
for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++) {
    c += Character.toString(x.charAt(i));
}
System.out.print(c);
if (c.equals("IND")) {
    System.out.println("India");
}
```

But the easiest way would be to use `String.substring(startIndex, endIndex)` for this.

```
String c = x.substring(0,3); // For USA
String c1 = x.substring(3,6); // For IND
```

Comment: I am not one of the downvoter but using `substring(0, 3)` instead of appending and looping is more generous. I think you should get rid of it. most of the time many users( including some reputed user ;) ) don't read complete answer

Comment: `But the easiest way would be to use...` - already suggested well before you edited your answer.

Comment: @camickr - 2 things. Firstly, I helped OP understand the problem and fix it. Giving a better solution should be secondary because, the OP may have constraints on using substring method(possible homework) and next, if you look at the revision history, you'll know if the edit was done before or after.

Comment: yes, R.J's answer is posted almost at the same time as camickr. not even concrete `1 min` difference.

Comment: Agreed, it is possibly homework which is why you don't provide the code just point the OP in the right direction. @sage `R.J's answer is posted almost at the same time` - the answer was edited (several times) although the timestamp doesn't always show this because you have 5 minutes to do edits BEFORE you get a revised timestamp is given.

Comment: @camickr - I didn't provide a code here. The OP has tried something and it didn't work. I just asked the OP to make a couple of changes, like appending the characters to the string, etc. Also, regarding the edits, the 5 min time period is given just for this purpose.

Comment: @camickr - Anyways, your vote is always your personal opinion and I've no say in it. I've no hard feelings against anybody or anything. I just wanted to clarify a few things. No love lost here!Cheers! :)

Comment: I didn't down vote. I was just making the point that two others made the suggestion well before you updated your answer. If you though it was a good idea it didn't really need to be mentioned a third time.

Comment: @camickr - Thanks for that! Really appreciate it. Though I felt that a suggestion could be duplicated in the answer, and that shouldn't be a problem, as long as the answer provides more to the OP than the answers already existing. My answer was primarily to address the OP's problem and not give the alternate. The alternate suggestion takes the backseat in my answer.

Comment: @camickr No the answer can repeated. If the OP chosen R.J s as the best answer then it should contain all possible solutions. Another viewer comes from google or any other reference will look only (most probably) the best answer and if the best answer can tell better then that would be better

Comment: @SubinJacob, `will look only (most probably) the best answer` - that is their problem. I believe people should look at all answers, they may learn something. Many times people add an answer after one has already been accepted, that doesn't mean it should be ignored. It is easier for somebody to read a posting with 2-3 unique answer that it is to read one where 5 people suggest the same thing (but use slightly different wording). The idea of the comments is to add more information to an existing answer if you think you can make the answer better, not to create a whole new answer.

Comment: substring really did not pop out in my mind when i was doing this omg!

Comment: @camickr That's what most of the viewers do. The best answer 'tick' would give more importance to the answer (though visually). Usually everyone would be in a hurry to find the answer. Only care other answers if the topic is that much interesting or if the best answer cannot be justified(satisfied). Anyway, duplicate answers are bad thing. But its better the best answer to show the complete summary (like community wiki)

Comment: A full detail explanation is always better than an answer with no head and no tail such as asking me to use substring. Not everyone will understand it.

Comment: @user2822351, The point of just mentioning the substring() method is to FORCE you to go to the API and read the API description of the method. You can't program if you don't know how to read the API. If you read the API and there is something you don't understand then you can always ask a follow up question. Also, by reading the API you may notice some other interesting methods that might come in handy in the future. You slowly accumulate knowledgy the more your read. `Give somebody a fish they eat for a day. Teach somebody to fish they eat for life!`.

Answer (score 2):

because when you do this

```
c = Character.toString(x.charAt(i));
```

the character at the ith position is getting stored in c and as it is in a for loop the only thing that would be stored there would be 'A'

use a substring instead of the `for` loop and `charAt`

```
c = x.substring(0,3); \\which would give you "USA"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `String.substring(...)` for this.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating through the string, but you only retain the last character because of this snippet:

```
c = Character.toString(x.charAt(i));
```

This should be:

```
c += Character.toString(x.charAt(i));
```

As this will append the current character iteration to the overall string. Replace the snippets with this fix, for the two loops. The `c` variable will build up the country code and will pass this condition this time:

```
if (c.equals("USA")) {
```

After the first loop and before the second loop, you will need to re-initialize the `c` variable:

```
c = "";
```

Once done, you can put that logic in a method of its own, so you avoid duplicate code within the loops.

This logic could be simplified by using `String.substring` instead, as others pointed out, as you work in details with the `String.charAt` which is more tedious. I thought though that pointing out your logic error was worth it, before giving you other pointers.

So talking about other approaches, you could try another one to your country code and name console output. Try to use a `HashMap` where the keys are the country code and the value is the country's name. You can iterate through the `HashMap` after that and print out both keys and values. That would be more high-level to your current solution and way shorter in code.

EDIT1: I offered the code to the last suggestion but I removed it, as I realized that giving code to assignment related questions is not encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

I would go another way, either try to add a terminal symbol like ";". If this is not possible you could check with `String.contains("USA")` if a certain country is set. But beaware it could happen that you will find a country not listed in because the combination of two others.

Comment: using a delimiter is a good idea but `String.contains()` is a very bad idea as this could happen "RSAMAS" (RSA -south africa and MAS is malaysia) but if you search for "SAM" (SAM - samoa) using contains it would return true which is not true

Comment: I know, thats the reason I metioned this already, but maybe my last sentence is not clear enough. Thanks for you example.

Comment: my bad man.. it wasn't clear what you were trying to say... :)

Answer (score 0):

With your logic, I thing it will be better to use

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

Get the substring for a start index and the end index and compare. Currently you are  just getting the character .With your current implementation you have to convert each character to String and append.

Comment: @camickr Check the timings before downvoating. How do I know if someone else is writing the same. I don't receive telepathic massages. Perhaps You do!!!!

Comment: @rookieB, you are 6 mins late from other such answer. But adding a little more notable information should be sufficient for avoiding downvote, even gaining upvote :)

Comment: The other answer was given well before this was posted. Also you are notified as you are typing if another answer has been received while you are typing,  so you can check that answer before completing your answer.

Comment: @Sage Is it sufficient for a downvote!!! That I did not load others answers while composing mine?? Anyways its ok. Thanks for giving me some advice. Seems people are really interested in timings. Funny though

Comment: @rookieB, i am not the down voter, but in the past when i was a new user(1 month before), i did same like you. Well i wasn't downvoted, but i was advised :)

Comment: I downvote because people pay more attention and I always leave a comment so people know (unlike the person who downvoted RJ's answer).

Comment: @rookieB: there is no reason to get fried up on downvote my friend. you can gain the lost reputation by adding more information helpful to the OP. try to load the answers as you type because if somebody has already answered the same thing you are typing its better to quit answering and upvote that answer. you can gain your reputation back by deleting your answer if you want to (no offense meant just letting you know)

Comment: @camickr I agree what you are trying to say. But it gives a wrong impression of being a wrong answer to anyone who uses SOF occasionally.

Comment: The suggestion to use substring has been mentioned in 5 answers and a comment under the answer. This is confusing. Occasional users will wonder why the same basic answer appears 5 times. Answers should be upvoted (not duplicated with slightly different wording) if you think it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

For the part of splitting, I would use Guava's [Splitter](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained), like so:

```
Splitter.fixedLength(3).split(x)
```

And for the part of matching abbreviation with full name, I would use an enum instead of equals comparing, it seems a little cleaner. So, a possible full result would be:

```
public class Example {

    public static enum Country {

        USA("United States of America"), IND("India");

        String fullName;

        Country(String fullName) {
                this.fullName = fullName;
            }

        String getFullName() {
            return fullName;
        }

    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "USAINDUSAIND";
        for (String s : Splitter.fixedLength(3).split(x)) {
            System.out.println(Country.valueOf(s).getFullName());
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT: Sorry about using third party, seemed clean to me. I agree with the other answers in using substring, but I like more thinking of everything as just one process and not two, so you can easily have a string of more than 2 abbreviations, like (example assuming the Enum as above)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "USAINDUSAIND";
    for (int i = 0;i < x.length();i += 3) {
        System.out.println(Country.valueOf(x.substring(i, i + 3).getFullName());
    }

}
```

Comment: Really, use a third party package to do something so basic?

Comment: sorry no 3rd party package..only basic programming